# Merging definition in an angular interface

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

For my routes I use an extra field that I set like this:

`app.config([
        '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) =>
        {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/Page',
                    {
                        title: 'My page',
                        templateUrl: 'Page.html',
                        controller: 'PageController'
                    });
        }
    ]);`

I tried adding `title` in my own definition file:

`declare module "angular" {
    namespace route {
        interface IRoute {
            title: string;
        }
    }
}`

But that doesn't seem to work, I tried various syntaxes, to no success. Anyone know the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround, you can use `any` and proceed as type casting are compile type your generated code will run perfectly.

you can also use like below which will check IRoute as well as any

`'$routeProvider', ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider | any) =>`

below shows only using any.

```
app.config([
        '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider: any) =>
        {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/Page',
                    {
                        title: 'My page',
                        templateUrl: 'Page.html',
                        controller: 'PageController'
                    });
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Yeah I did that for now, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: yap agree. the best way is angularJS typings to provide some mechanism but its not available now. most of the people are moving towards anguar (version2/4) so with less audiance they might not do it.